# How do you set the PDF Print Dialog Presets (e.g. DuplexMode) in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf-generation

I am using `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile` to create a PDF in an iPad app. The file is encrypted using a password. I would like to set the PDF Print Dialog Presets in particular DuplexMode so that the document will default to duplex printing. I assume I should be using `kCGPDFContextKeywords` to set DuplexMode to DuplexFlipLongEdge. 
Can someone provide an example of how this is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be done using the standard iOS PDF API. The auxiliary dictionary keys are a fixed set that support only setting some document information and the password.
There is no support for setting the DuplexMode.